# Copy intent / change source activity and destination class

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to change to a new Activity over an Intent, but in my current Intent there are all my ExtraStrings as parameters. So decided to copy it with

```
Intent next = getIntent();
```

but how to change the source activity and the destiantion class now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the better solution would be create your own Intent with your destination class and use [Intent.putExtras(Intent src)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtras%28android.content.Intent%29) to put extra data of original intent to new one.

And of course you can use [Intent.setClass](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClass%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29) or `setClassName()` just to replace destination class.

Comment: yes, i know that therfore i copied the old intent, i just want to know how i can replace the data, that i usually give to the constructor.

Comment: You can use setClass/setClassName methods too. See my clarified answer.

Comment: that method takes a string too, what to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass your data in bundle..

**FirstActivity:**

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, activity1.class);
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putString("key", "value");
mIntent.putExtra("keyBundle", mBundle);
```

**SecondActivity:**

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, activity2.class);
mIntent.putExtras(getIntent().getExtras().getBundle("keyBundle"));
```